# "stack corruption detected" when using glGetProgramiv

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I am writing native Android OpenGLES 2 code.

When loading shaders (shader loading code is very similar to the NDK sample "hello-gl2"), my program does not link (shaders themselves compile without errors).

This code:

```
GLint linkStatus = GL_FALSE;
GLCALL(glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus));
if (linkStatus != GL_TRUE) {
```

Returns false, so I proceed to calling

```
LOGE("Could not link program, gathering log...");
GLint bufLength = 0;
GLCALL(glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &bufLength));
```

Which never returns and crashes my app.
LogCat shows in red:

```
04-19 15:24:55.369: A/<unknown>(29293): stack corruption detected: aborted
04-19 15:24:55.379: I/ActivityManager(101): Process x.x.x (pid 29293) has died.
```

I can assume that something goes wrong inside the log retrieving function, because I pass it a normal GLint reference, and this is the same code from the Google example...

I've tried skipping the length querying and just query the log directly, but it generates the same error.

I could post here the whole GLSL shader code but it would be more valuable to just have the log function working so I can debug it myself...

The full shader loading code:

```
GLuint OpenGLESHelper::loadShader(GLenum shaderType, const char* pSource) {
    GLuint shader;
    GLCALL(shader = glCreateShader(shaderType));
    if (shader) {
        GLCALL(glShaderSource(shader, 1, &pSource, NULL));
        GLCALL(glCompileShader(shader));
        GLint compiled = 0;
        GLCALL(glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled));
        if (!compiled) {
            LOGE("Could not compile shader, retrieving log...");
            GLint infoLen = 0;
            GLCALL(glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen));

            // Workaround
            if (infoLen == 0)
                infoLen = 4096;

            if (infoLen) {
                char* buf = (char*) malloc(infoLen);
                if (buf) {
                    GLCALL(glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLen, NULL, buf));
                    LOGE("Could not compile shader %d:\n%s\n", shaderType, buf);
                    free(buf);
                }
                GLCALL(glDeleteShader(shader));
                shader = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return shader;
}

ShaderProgram* OpenGLESHelper::createProgram(const char* pVertexSource,
        const char* pFragmentSource) {
    GLuint vertexShader = loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, pVertexSource);
    if (!vertexShader) {
        return 0;
    }

    GLuint pixelShader = loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, pFragmentSource);
    if (!pixelShader) {
        return 0;
    }

    GLuint programId;
    GLCALL(programId = glCreateProgram());
    if (programId) {
        GLCALL(glAttachShader(programId, vertexShader));
        GLCALL(glAttachShader(programId, pixelShader));
        GLCALL(glLinkProgram(programId));
        GLint linkStatus = GL_FALSE;
        GLCALL(glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus));
        if (linkStatus != GL_TRUE) {
            LOGE("Could not link program, gathering log...");
            GLint bufLength = 0;
            GLCALL(glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &bufLength));

            if (bufLength) {
                char* buf = (char*) malloc(bufLength);
                if (buf) {
                    GLCALL(glGetProgramInfoLog(programId, bufLength, NULL, buf));
                    LOGE("Could not link program:\n%s\n", buf);
                    free(buf);
                }
            }
            GLCALL(glDeleteProgram(programId));
            programId = 0;
        }
    }

    ShaderProgram* program = new ShaderProgram;
    program->mProgramHandle = programId;

    GLCALL(
            program->mPositionAttributeHandle = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "vPosition"));
    GLCALL(
            program->mTexCoordAttributeHandle = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "a_TexCoordinate"));
    GLCALL(
            program->mTextureUniformHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "rubyTexture"));
    GLCALL(
            program->mTextureSizeUniformHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "rubyTextureSize"));

    return program;
}
```

The used preprocessor macros:

```
  #ifdef ANDROID_DEBUG_GL_CALLS
#define GLCALLLOG(x, before) \
    do { \
        if (before) \
            LOGD("calling '%s' (%s:%d)", x, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        else \
            LOGD("returned from '%s' (%s:%d)", x, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
    } while (false)
#else
#define GLCALLLOG(x, before) do {  } while (false)
#endif

#define GLCALL(x) \
    do { \
        GLCALLLOG(#x, true); \
        (x); \
        GLCALLLOG(#x, false); \
        checkGlError(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
    } while (false)

#define GLTHREADCHECK \
    do { \
        assert(pthread_self() == _main_thread); \
    } while (false)

#else
#define GLCALL(x) do { (x); } while (false)
#define GLTHREADCHECK do {  } while (false)
#endif
```

**UPDATE**

There was one particular shader pair which generated this weird behavior.

I found 2 other shader pairs that compile correctly, but when linked, generate a log with just "Link failed." - no info beside that.

Then I tried those 2 shader pairs (exact same APK) on a Jelly Bean AVD with GPU emulation, and they link together perfectly and my game works there.

Very, very, very inconsistent stuff here...
Is the problem with my HTC Desire? 
What would be a good reference device for checking if my shaders are good or not?

Comment: Note this is a stack corruption complaint, detected by gcc's -fstack-check; something has trashed the stack of whatever method it's failing in.  A return of zero from glGetShaderiv means there's no log to retrieve -- apparently it has failed but has nothing useful to say.  What device are you using?

Comment: My device is HTC Desire stock ROM. As said, I don't get zero from the 2nd call to glGetShaderiv - the call never returns and I get the stack corruption.

Comment: Do you get a native crash dump in the log?  Can you tell what method it's in when it fails?  Depending on the size + complexity of the shader, you may have some success removing parts until you get something that doesn't crash.  (If it crashes with a trivial shader, you know your problem is elsewhere.)

Comment: No crash dump - just that "stack corruption" message, right after entering glGetProgramiv. The same shaders work perfectly on the AVD, I guess it's a device bug.

Comment: Perhaps -- but there are a lot of games with a lot of shaders that don't crash, so if you can narrow it down to a specific sequence you may be able to work around whatever the problem is.