# stack protection triggered by eglMakeCurrent

Tags: gcc, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, lto

We have come across a weird device, named Motorla RAZR i, with x86 CPU and Android version 4.1.2 (circa 2013).

This device crashes sometimes on GL operations in native code. We finally reduced this error to just few lines of innocent function calls:

```
void stackCorrupt() {
  const EGLint configAttrs[] = {EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT, EGL_NONE};
  const EGLint contextAttrs[] = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE};
  const EGLint const surfaceAttrs[] = {EGL_WIDTH, 16, EGL_HEIGHT, 16, EGL_NONE};

  EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
  eglInitialize(display, 0, 0);

  EGLint numConfigs;
  EGLConfig config;
  eglChooseConfig(display, configAttrs, &config, 1, &numConfigs);

  EGLContext context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, contextAttrs);
  EGLSurface surface = eglCreatePbufferSurface(display, config, surfaceAttrs);

  // commenting out this call makes the stack clean again
  eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context);

  // only to know that the context is good
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "native-lib", "GL_RENDERER %s", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));

  // Cleanup
  eglDestroySurface(display, surface);
  eglDestroyContext(display, context);
  eglTerminate(display);
}
```

When compiled with `-fstack-protector-strong` (which is default if I understand correctly), calling this function on the specific device invariably causes

```
 F /system/bin/app_process: stack corruption detected: aborted
```

But if I use `-fno-stack-protector`, execution continues as if nothing bad happened. Which may (if I understand the situation correctly) become a trap for any further execution. Even more dangerous (because not explicit), adding **-flto** to CFLAGS hides the crash.

In the code above, I removed error checking for brevity. Actually, all calls succeed. Also, the *Cleanup* section does not change the stack thrashing behavior of **eglMakeCurrent()**.

I would be really glad to create some sandbox to execute such code safely without endangering the rest of my app.

**PS**

1. I came across another case of strange stack corruption on Android, *["stack corruption detected" when using glGetProgramiv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104896/stack-corruption-detected-when-using-glgetprogramiv)*, but it seems that no cure was proposed.
2. In the test case, but not in the real-world app, [release](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglMakeCurrent.xhtml) of the egl context helps: I call `eglMakeCurrent(display, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_CONTEXT)` before *Cleanup*.
3. Disassembly shows that **-flto** turns off stack protector. This should not be a big disappointment: if our goal is to optimize calls, it's stupid to waste time checking?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;NR:** this is a false alarm. The EGL library on the device (which was never updated since 2013) does not respect the TLS conventions that were introduced years later, and the new NDK (we use the stable r13) falsely blames our innocent function in stack smashing.

I found a message in gcc maillist of [Nov 2015](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2015-11/msg00060.html) referring to a fix of [Apr 2013](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-04/msg00764.html):

> ### x86 android: change -fstack-protector guard default to TLS
>
> Folks that are compiling
>   native code for pre-4.2 Android will most likely be using older
>   versions of the Android NDK in any case.
>
> I would like to propose removing the Bionic exception, e.g. changing
>   the code to read:
>
> ```
>  /* Handle stack protector */
>  if (!opts_set->x_ix86_stack_protector_guard)
>    opts->x_ix86_stack_protector_guard = SSP_TLS;
> ```

The assumption is wrong, our code runs same jar's and so's on all platforms from 4.0 to 7.0 and we don't want to use old versions of NDK for some of target devices. Actually, NDK r14 still provides support for android-9 (a.k.a. [2.3 GINGERBREAD](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3.html)).

Unfortunately, this means that at least on this device we must run the debug version of our C++ code with **-fno-stack-protector**. Luckily, the release build (**APP_OPTIM=release**) uses LTO and thus stack protector is disabled.